# How to delete frame on click of button? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, frames

```
import tkinter as tk

global counter
counter = 0

def addframe():
    global counter
    newtask_frame = tk.Frame(highlightbackground="green",highlightthickness=1, master = intrldisp_frame)
    newtaskheading_label = tk.Label(newtask_frame, text="Added frame")
    newtaskheading_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    newtaskdel_button = tk.Button(newtask_frame,text="del", command = newtask_frame.grid_forget())
    newtaskdel_button.grid(row=1,column = 0,pady=5,padx=10)
    newtask_frame.grid(row=counter,column=0,sticky = "nsew",pady=10,padx=5)
    counter+=1

window = tk.Tk()

tasksinfo_frame = tk.Frame(highlightbackground="red",highlightthickness=2)
tasksinfo_frame.grid(row=0,pady=10)

addtask_button = tk.Button(tasksinfo_frame, text = "add",activebackground="blue",command = addframe)
addtask_button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

intrldisp_frame = tk.Frame(highlightbackground="blue",highlightthickness=1, master = window)
intrldisp_frame.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky = "n", padx=5)

window.mainloop()
```

So, I wrote a function for a button that creates a frame on click as can be read from the code above. I have also added a delete button in each frame that gets added, but I cannot figure out how to get the delete button to work.

How do I delete the frame when clicked on the del button? Is there any way to add id to them= frames? Do I have to use OOP for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code works when `command = newtask_frame.grid_forget()` is changed to `command = newtask_frame.grid_forget`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I delete the frame when clicked on the del button?

You need to call the `destroy` method of the frame.

```
newtaskdel_button = tk.Button(..., command = newtask_frame.destroy)
```